# mysql subquery field not exist but query all

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
mysql> select id,mr_id,type from oh_mr_ocr_sub_info where mr_id in

 (select mr_id from oh_mr_base_info) limit 2;

+----+-------+--------------+
| id | mr_id | type         |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  2 |     7 | inhospital   |
|  3 |     7 | chemotherapy |
+----+-------+--------------+

2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select mr_id from oh_mr_base_info;

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'mr_id' in 'field list'
```

`oh_mr_base_info` does not contain field `mr_id`;
but return all `oh_mr_ocr_sub_info`  data? why?

Answer (score 0):

Its the way, SQL works :)

If you give alias to the tables, you will see that the query will not work anymore

```
select a1.id,
       a1.mr_id,
       a1.type 
  from oh_mr_ocr_sub_info a1
 where a1.mr_id in (select b1.mr_id 
                   from oh_mr_base_info b1)
 limit 2;
```

The above will give you an error, saying that b1.mr_id is an invalid column. However instead if you write a1.mr_id it will work without any problem.

Its not exactly about table aliases, but the table columns. it sees that mr_id doesn't need to exist in B1, it can exist in a1 as well. Its same as selecting a constant

```
select 111 from oh_mr_base_info;
```

The query will return 111 as long as there are any number of records available in oh_mr_base_info. Always advisable to use table aliases for these kind of problems

Comment: thanks, this solve my problem, but why ? is there any acticles about mysql subquery execution process

Comment: It's a "correlated subquery". A subquery in the `WHERE` clause can refer to columns in the outer query. This is usually done to allow comparing rows in the subquery to the current row in the main query, but it also works in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization.html   This is about Subquery Optimization , it turns to EXISTS